# How to make external template for backbone view

Tags: templates, backbone.js, routes

I am new to things like angular and backbone and am trying to understand the structure better. I built some views but if I leave any spaces in the template chunk it breaks everything.

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: '<h1>Home</h1><p>This is the first test. I think this is the way.</p>',
      initialize: function () {
          this.render();
      },
      render: function () {
          this.$el.html(this.template);
      }
  });


var AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: '<h1>About</h1><p>This is the second test. I think this is the way.</p>',
      initialize: function () {
          this.render();
      },
      render: function () {
          this.$el.html(this.template);
      }
  });

var CoolView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: '<h1>Cool</h1><p>This is the third test. I think this is the way.</p>',
      initialize: function () {
          this.render();
      },
      render: function () {
          this.$el.html(this.template);
      }
  });

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {          
          '': 'homeRoute',
          'home': 'homeRoute',
          'about': 'aboutRoute',
          'cool': 'coolRoute',  
      },
      homeRoute: function () {
          var homeView = new HomeView();          
          $("#content").html(homeView.el);
      },
      aboutRoute: function () {
          var aboutView = new AboutView();          
          $("#content").html(aboutView.el);
      },
      coolRoute: function () {
          var coolView = new CoolView();          
          $("#content").html(coolView.el);
      }
  });

  var appRouter = new AppRouter();
  Backbone.history.start();
```

Is there a way to make this pull from external templates outside of the javascript. What's best practices if the pages are very elaborate?

Here is my jsfiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/k4ox8yap/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a javascript module loader like [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/) (which you'll probably find yourself doing when the application gets more complicated!) then the templates can be loaded from an external source using the [RequireJs text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text).

For example you might have a file called `home.js` which could look like:

```
require([ "backbone", "underscore", "text!templates/template.html" ],
    function( Backbone, _, template ) {

       return Backbone.View.extend({
             template: _.template( template ),
             initialize: function () {
               this.render();
             },
             render: function () {
               this.$el.html(this.template);
             }
        });
    }
);
```

Then an `app.js` file could contain your application logic and require your views:

```
require([ "backbone", "jquery", "home.js" ],
        function( Backbone, $, HomeView ) {

           var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
              routes: {          
                '': 'homeRoute',
                'home': 'homeRoute',
                // etc 
              },
              homeRoute: function () {
                 var homeView = new HomeView();          
                 $("#content").html(homeView.el);
              }, // etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify your template in your html

```
<script id='CoolViewTpl' type='template'>
      <h1>Cool</h1><p>This is the third test. I think this is the way.</p>
</script>
```

Then in your render func, simply select the template by ID and get the content.

```
var CoolView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: "#CoolViewTpl",
      initialize: function () {
          this.render();
      },
      render: function () {
          this.$el.html($(this.template).html());
      }
  });
```